# Working with closures inside loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so I've read [this closure question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example/19323214#19323214) and tried to fit the idea behind my script. This is what I have so far but the console is telling me that nameOfLoan[j] does not exist and I can't figure out why.

```js
$('body').on('keyup', '.qForms', function() {
var nameOfLoan = [];

 var loanOfName = function(t) {
   $('body').on('keyup', '.loanNameV'+t, function() {
     console.log('hi');
    var loanN = $('.loanNameV'+t).val();
    $('.nameLoan'+t).text(loanN);
   });
  };

 for (var t=1; t < z; t++) {
  nameOfLoan[t] = loanOfName(t);
 }

 for (var j=1; j < z; j++) {
  nameOfLoan[j]();
 }
});
```

Comment: Is `i` defined at `for` loop ?

Comment: Not based on what is here. What is `i`?

Comment: At `nameOfLoan[t] = loanOfName[t];`, but `loanOfName` is a function.

Comment: i is defined earlier on in my script before this section and it =s 2 to begin with but can increase and decrease depending on how many dynamically created elements there are @colecmc

Comment: extra function inside `loanOfName()` isn't needed either. `loanOfName(t)` creates a closure for the code inside it

Comment: Seems like we're missing some pieces. Can you provide a full snippet? Or post the code to jsbin?

Comment: What is `z` ? What is expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314 I have dynamically created elements that I want to apply a keyup function to. Essentially everytime you write in one of the text forms of a dynamically created elements the text inside the "title" of these elements changes to whatever is being typed in the text form

Comment: Tried with only first `keyup` event ? Can include example `html` ?